Как добавить иконку в QTreeView?
Как добавить иконку в QTreeView?

К примеру иконку перед "main.spct". По типу такого:


main.py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

tree = \
{
    'Project':
    {
        'src':
        {
            'main.spct': {}
        }
    }
}


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.populateTree(tree, model.invisibleRootItem())
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'File Manager')
        self.tree_view.expandAll()
        self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(self.onSelectionChanged)

    def populateTree(self, children, parent):
        for child in children:
            child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(child)
            parent.appendRow(child_item)
            if isinstance(children, dict):
                self.populateTree(children[child], child_item)

    def onSelectionChanged(self, *args):
        for sel in self.tree_view.selectedIndexes():
            val = sel.data()
            while sel.parent().isValid():
                sel = sel.parent()
                val = sel.data()+ val
            print(val)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


Некоторые варианты выглядят так:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


tree = \
{
    'Project':
    {
        'src':
        {
            'main.spct': {}
        }
    },
    
    "No Category": 
    {
        'New Game':
        {
            'Playnite': {'Never'}
        }
    }
}

class GroupDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GroupDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self._plus_icon = QtGui.QIcon('Ok.png')     # установите свои изображения 
        self._minus_icon = QtGui.QIcon('ball.png')  # ...

    def initStyleOption(self, option, index):
        super(GroupDelegate, self).initStyleOption(option, index)
        if not index.parent().isValid():
            is_open = bool(option.state & QtWidgets.QStyle.State_Open)
            option.features |= QtWidgets.QStyleOptionViewItem.HasDecoration
            option.icon = self._minus_icon if is_open else self._plus_icon


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.tree_view = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tree_view)

# +++
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(128, 128)
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.green)
        self.icon = QtGui.QIcon(pixmap)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()                           # +++
        self.populateTree(tree, model.invisibleRootItem())
            
        delegate = GroupDelegate(self)
        self.tree_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)        
        
        self.tree_view.setModel(model)
        model.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'File Manager')
        self.tree_view.expandAll()
        self.tree_view.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(
            self.onSelectionChanged)
        
    def populateTree(self, children, parent):
        for child in children:
            child_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(child)
            
            child_item.setIcon(self.icon)                              # +++
            if child == "main.spct":
                icon = QtGui.QIcon('icons/qtlogo.png')                 # ...
                icon.pixmap(155, 55)
                child_item.setIcon(icon)
                    
            parent.appendRow(child_item)
            if isinstance(children, dict):
                self.populateTree(children[child], child_item)

    def onSelectionChanged(self, *args):
        for sel in self.tree_view.selectedIndexes():
            val = sel.data()
            while sel.parent().isValid():
                sel = sel.parent()
                val = sel.data() + '/' + val
            print(f'val = {val}\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



Спасибо вам огромное

@Егор пожалуйста.
